# Android Studio Dolphin's Logcat stopped working for the filter?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-dolphin

With 'Android Studio Dolphin | 2021.3.1', I am trying to get logs for my application with the Classname (which is used as TAG for Logs) but nothing is showing up.
Sometimes, it doesn't show any logs with the filter package:mine or package:'my.package.name'.
Is this a known issue?

Update: reported on google's board : https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/258502193

Comment: Based on the changelogs I'm suspecting there are problems with Logcat V2, however whenever I bump into this, I try the following and usually helps: 

1. Close the current Logcat tab and open a new one.
2. Disconnect the device/emulator and reconnect.
3. Restart IDE.

Comment: Have you configured your logcat formatting options ?

Comment: I tried all the filters. This issue occurs at random, I recently faced it again when I had multiple logcat tabs open with different filters but not even a single one showing any log related to that keyword(class names in my case).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution(time-consuming) which helped me is:

1. Close the current/all Logcat tab/s
2. Disconnect the device/emulator.
3. Restart IDE. (wait for some time if possible)
4. Start new Logcat windows.

Update:
The second solution is to turn off the experimental Logcat window:

1. Select Android Studio > Preferences
2. Go to the Experimental tab
3. Un-check the 'Enable new Logcat tool window' option.

Update (Nov,22):
The quick solution that worked for me:

1. Change your Log.d() statements to System.out.println(), and filter it with the keyword added in println() statements.

Comment: First option does not work for us, we tried multiple times on different systems. No success. The second option is a regression, the new tools is much better than the old one.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem (also using . I'm assuming it's related to the new Logcat tool window, so I just turned it off. The 'old' version is working for me. Maybe they'll fix it in the next update and I can try the new version.

- File > Settings > Experimental > Logcat
- then clear the checkbox for 'Enable new Logcat tool window'

Comment: I don't see these settings for Android Studio Dolphin

Comment: Indeed the old visualization still works, but that is not a solution. The new visualization is better in many ways. So reverting is a bad deal.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a bug, there are two options, I prefer the second way cause it doesn't restart the whole IDE.

*First solution:*
Select the **File** menu > **Invalidate Caches** > **Invalidate and Restart**

*Second solution:*
Open the terminal from the bottom panel (tabs on the left corner).
Run these two commands:

```
adb kill-server
adb start-server
```